# Force period in inputmode='decimal' for Safari regardless of culture

Tags: html, safari, mobile-safari

I have the following input for a DOB field:

```
<input maxlength="10" class="inputText" type="text" inputmode="decimal" placeholder="dd.mm.YYYY">
```

However, some of my users get the comma instead of period decimal separator (due to their locale) on the numeric keyboard in Safari:

[image]

Is there any way to force the locale for this input? Or get the comma and period as you do in Android?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hack.

```html
<input onkeydown="hack()" />
```

```js
function hack(event) {
     if(String.fromCharCode(it.which) == '¼') {
            input.value += "."
     }
}
```

of course you can have another handler if you use React, Vuejs, etc.

This is just a gist for understanding